# Armature rig with mirrored object without applying mirror modifier

Tags: rigging, armature, mirror

I'm building a robot, and am using a mirror modifier on all the individual parts (all parts are individual "hard-surface" objects connected via joints).

I now want to add an armature without applying the mirror modifiers.

I know that I can create vertex groups, (named the same as the bones) with `.L` and `.R` and then add an `Armature` modifier, but this gets very tedious since I have lots of small individual parts, and I need to make sure all vertices are in the correct group every time I make a change.

What is the recommended approach here?

Comment: You can parent With Empty Groups, it will create as many vertex groups as you have bones but it won't affect any vertex to any group, you'll do it manually: Select the vertices, go into the Object Data panel > Vertex Groups, in the list select the vertex group the vertices are supposed to be part of, and click on the Assign button under the list

Comment: @moonboots maybe I'm not understanding what you're saying, but that means that I still have to assign all vertices to a vertex group right? So every time I have a new object I need to assign it again?

Comment: if the parts of your robot are different objects, and not diffent meshes within the same object, then you can select the object, shift select the armature, switch it to Pose mode, select the bone you want, and Ctrl P (Parent) > Bone. In that case no need for vertex groups, and no Armature modifier. This is the alternative for objects like robots, machines, etc

Comment: @moonboots that's what I had initially, but that doesn't work with the mirror modifier, does it?

Comment: no, as the mesh and the mirrored meshed are part of the same object, you first need to apply the modifier and separate the 2 parts as 2 objects

Comment: Mh ok thanks @moonboots
So if I'm not mistaken I have two options? Either assign vertex groups in all individual objects and use the armature modifier, or apply the mirror modifier and parent the individual objects (a process, I will have to repeat every time I make a change to the model).

Comment: In the first option it's much more convenient to join all the objects into one object, and assign each mesh to the good vertex group. To select a mesh press L. The second option is a simple parentage of separate objects to bones

Comment: Thanks... unfortunately option 1 is not an option for me because I'm using different modifiers an the objects. Oh well.. copying all objects it is then.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 rigging options for objects like robots, machines, manufactured objects, etc:

Either you merge all the objects into one and parent with the *With Empty Groups* option (and later assign the vertices to the vertex groups they are supposed to be part of), or you keep the objects separated and you simply parent to each bones.

In the second case, you'll need to apply the *Mirror* modifier and separate the objects (<kbd>P</kbd> *(Separate) > Selection*). Then select an object, shift select the armature, switch it to *Pose* mode, select the bone, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> *(Set Parent to) > Bone*.